# Chi-squared test where observations can have multiple categories

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I am investigating patterns in click-order on images. A user is asked to click on an image in 5 places (can be the same place). This sequence of 5 clicks makes up a graphical password. I am looking for patterns in the order in which users click e.g. they scan from left to right i.e. x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < x_5 where x_i is the x co-ordinate of the ith click.

The categories that I am considering are left to right, right to left, top to bottom, bottom to top, clockwise and anticlockwise. I want to see if there is a difference in click-order for populations with different attributes e.g. are women more likely to have a click-order of left to right than men? For this I planned a chi-square test of independence probably Fisher's exact test because of a low sample size.

My problem is that a user can be in multiple categories e.g. they may click left to right and bottom to top making a diagonal pattern. I am assuming that this isn't allowed in a contingency table so will I have to split the patterns into mutually exclusive sets i.e. test left to right against right to left, top to bottom against bottom to top etc.?

Also would I have to include users that do not fit into any category e.g. have left-right, right-left and neither as my categories for testing the horizontal plane?

Is there a way to test the independence of the pattern as a whole (may include more than one category) from an attribute (such as gender)?